# How to name/structure Redux action?

Tags: redux, action

I'm loving redux, but I'm not sure if I'm creating actions in a consistent way.

I feel like action types for API calls are pretty straightforward, let's say my API is doing something:

```
type: DO_SOMETHING_REQUEST   payload: nothing or data we want to send
type: DO_SOMETHING_SUCCEEDED payload: the data returned
type: DO_SOMETHING_FAILED    payload: the error (if we care about our users)
```

That's all dandy. However when we talk about actions that are a bit more front-end related, like changing a state switch that controls showing a modal, I see two distinct approaches.

```
type: CAT_PICTURE_MODAL_SHOW
type: CAT_PICTURE_MODAL_HIDE
```

or

```
type: CAT_PICTURE_MODAL_SET_VISIBLITY   payload: true / false
```

I tend to go for the first option rather than the second, and set the state switch explicitly. I feel it's more descriptive, even if you write a bit more code.

Is it only for boolean kind of data that this show/hide, on/off, left/right, cute/ugly action types are recommended? Or does it depend on how you think the data will evolve in the future? A modal is obviously not going to get an action CAT_PICTURE_MODAL_HIDE_BETTER, but you could easily imagine CAT_PICTURE_LIKE to have a (high) numerical value in the payload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an interesting question, and I don't think there is a black/white answer. Personally, I'm always conscious about the amount of code I write: the more code you write, the more you will have to maintain later.

I only use the multi-action method for async requests, when I can't dispatch the start and result of the action at the same time. Otherwise, I personally feel it's more concise and straightforward to have single action creators.

I don't think this discussion is limited to redux, but goes broader to any kind of function in your code: if you're creating a counter that you want to increment / decrease: do you write to methods `incrementCounter()` and `decreaseCounter()` or just one `changeCounterBy(amountToIncrease)`? The answer on this question is probably an answer to your original question. Anyway, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond Pelle!
I guess I tend to go more for incrementCounter and decreaseCounter, just because I'm so used to seeing them in tutorials, and because I would expect the increment to always be 1. I get your point though, less code is less maintenance.